# Power Automate - Compare StartDate to current date?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

We are looking to compare the calendar start date with the current date in flow. Currently we are pulling the start date through a filter query like this:

```
formatDateTime('EventDate','M-d-yyy hh:mm')
```

and comparing to this:

```
formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),3),'M-d-yyyy hh:mm')
```

I am getting this error currently: "Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Get_items' inputs at line '1' and column '17987': 'In function 'formatDateTime', the value provided for date time string 'EventDate' was not valid. The datetime string must match ISO 8601 format."

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I test with the same formula to convert event start date and it works fine in my end. The if condition returns correct result on different conditions.

Here is the logic of my demo flow, please have a check:
[image]
I use get item to get the start date of a certain event in the calendar list and convert the start time dynamic content to the format I need. Almost same with yours.

According to the error message, it seems the format of the event date column is not in the supported format. Would you like to provide the settings of your event date column? I test with the default start time column and a custom date & time column of default settings. Both of them works fine with the flow above.

**Update:**

The two formulas used are displayed below:

```
formatDateTime(outputs('Get_item')?['body/Event_x0020_Date'],'M-d-yyy hh:mm')

formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),3),'M-d-yyyy hh:mm')
```

[image]

I just directly use the outputs of the data compose action in the if condition

Comment: Oh okay, ill give this a shot. Looking at your IF condition, i did mine different (which was wrong). In the Get items block i added a filter query with these contents

@{formatDateTime('EventDate','M-d-yyyy hh:mm')} eq '@{variables('current_time')}' and Status eq 'Not Started'

Comment: And my start time settings is the default Calendar start time seetings

Comment: Can you send the full expressions in your compose blocks? and the comparison. If that is ok.

Comment: @wsmith42 Sure, I just updated the formula in the reply.

Comment: @wsmith42 I am assuming that the get items action may have something to do with your issue. Would you like to provide the structure of your flow if it ok for you?

Comment: I actually got it working, so thank you! my only issue now is that when testing adding a reoccurring item, the flow doesnt seem to trigger. It seems to only recognize the first date the calendar item was started on as the start date.

Comment: Mostly the right approach. I found I needed to add a comparison of the `ticks` of each formula, which would make it: `ticks(formatDateTime(outputs('Get_item')?['body/Event_x0020_Date'],'M-d-yyy HH:mm:ss tt'))` and `ticks(formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),3),'M-d-yyyy HH:mm:ss tt'))` -- but I added the `formatDateTime` parts to separate Compose objects before that, and then added its outputs to the Conditional with the `ticks()` surrounding the outputs in each.

Answer (score 0):

You could Initialize a variable like the following below and then do a IF condition.

```
@{add(div(sub(ticks(utcNow()),ticks('1900-01-01')),864000000000),2)}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry can i ask what that function does? (@{add(div(sub(ticks(utcNow()),ticks('1900-01-01')),864000000000),2)}) The hope is to compare the current date vs the start date they added for the event in the calendar.

Comment: You need to store both current date and start date into a variable. Instead of utcNow() in the formula, replace it with the date you are trying to convert. This function converts the date into an integer, and then you can do an IF condition seeing which number is greater than the other. Think of this number as a date in Microsoft Excel. When you convert a date in Excel, it turns it into a number like the picture above. Please let me know if you need help.

Comment: For example, initialize an integer variable, call it EventDate, and use this function @{add(div(sub(ticks('EventDate'),ticks('1900-01-01')),864000000000),2)} and then initialize another variable for CurrentDate and do the similar steps.

Comment: Yea i may need more private help if thats an option? Im very new to sharepoint would appreciate the help

Comment: To make sure i understand:
1. Initialize two variables (current time and StartDate) with ticks function
2.  compare two variables (if one is less than the other)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to build a sequence of numbers with the dates being ordered by day, month and year this way, when converting to integer, it's easy to compare

```
int(formatDateTime(utcNow()),'yyyyMMdd'))
```

if you need add day for exemple, you can use

```
int(formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),variables('extraDays')),'yyyyMMdd'))
```

and the other date like this

```
int(formatDateTime(variables('FinalDate'),'yyyyMMdd'))
```

Based on your example, you can put hours and minutes without any problems, just remove the special characters and spaces

but by the definition of the error you are having, I believe it is because of the way you are writing the variable